# how to output the adjacency group from edge list?

Tags: r, igraph

Edge list:

```
el <- rbind(c(6,11), c(1,8), c(8,12), c(11,17), 
            c(6,7), c(7,11), c(18,19), c(6,16))
```

In this case, 6,11,17,7,16 connect, 1,8,2 connect, and 18,19 connect with each other. So there are three groups. How to get these groups from this edge list using R?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for connected components: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory) This is (somewhat confusingly) called `clusters` in igraph. To get the list of communities is relatively complicated:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(data.frame(el))
clu <- clusters(g)
comp <- tapply(seq_along(clu$membership), clu$membership, simplify = FALSE, function(x) x)
lapply(comp, function(x) V(g)$name[x])
# $`1`
# [1] "6"  "11" "7"  "17" "16"
#
# $`2`
# [1] "1"  "8"  "12"
#
# $`3`
# [1] "18" "19"
```